Assess performance of elements within an R function
I know it is possible to estimate the time it takes to complete a function (e.g., with sys.time(), but is there a way to benchmark a function and see which element within the function takes the longest/shortest?
So for example, given the code below, I should be able to performance test the function and determine for run 1, function_long is a bottleneck but for run 2, function_custom is the issue.
function_short <- function(){
  Sys.sleep(2)
}

function_long <- function(){
  sys.sleep(8)
}

function_custom <- function(x){
  sys.sleep(x)
}

function_to_test <- function(x){
  print("Starting function")
  
  print("2 second rest..")
  function_short()
  
  print("8 second rest..")
  function_long()
  
  print(paste0(x), " second rest..")
  function_custom(x)
}

# test these
## run 1
function_to_test(1)

## run 2
function_to_test(10)



Have you tried Rprof(), or one of the wrappers for it (e.g. in RStudio)?

profvis::profvis(function_to_test(1)) might work for you here. https://github.com/r-lib/profvis

Edit: There are a few different options. You could use the built in profiler like this
  function_short <- function(){
    Sys.sleep(2)
  }
  
  function_long <- function(){
    Sys.sleep(8)
  }
  
  function_custom <- function(x){
    Sys.sleep(x)
  }
  
  
function_custom <- function(x){
  Sys.sleep(x)
}

function_to_test <- function(x){
  print("Starting function")
  
  print("2 second rest..")
  function_short()
  
  print("8 second rest..")
  function_long()
  
  print(paste0(x), " second rest..")
  function_custom(x)
} 


Rprof('my_fun')

function_to_test(2)
#> [1] "Starting function"
#> [1] "2 second rest.."
#> [1] "8 second rest.."
#> Warning in print.default(paste0(x), " second rest.."): NAs introduced by
#> coercion
#> Error in print.default(paste0(x), " second rest.."): invalid printing digits -2147483648

Rprof(NULL)




Created on 2024-08-16 with reprex v2.1.1
and in the terminal run 'R CMD Rprof my_fun which catch some of the  bottle necks. Alternatively you could do
script = 'function_short <- function(){
  Sys.sleep(2)
}

function_long <- function(){
  Sys.sleep(8)
}

function_custom <- function(x){
  Sys.sleep(x)
}


function_custom <- function(x){
  Sys.sleep(x)
}

function_to_test <- function(x){
  print("Starting function")
  
  print("2 second rest..")
  function_short()
  
  print("8 second rest..")
  function_long()
  
  print(paste0(x), " second rest..")
  function_custom(x)
} '

writeLines(script, con = "script.R")

source('script.R')

profvis::profvis(function_to_test(2))


Which will open an interactive view of the run time for each parts of the function.
Created on 2024-08-16 with reprex v2.1.1

I think that is a good solution IF the function is relatively simple and I want to alter the original function code. I can keep this in the back pocket

This is not what OP wants I suspect. This only prints the runtime of a whole function; it does not report which parts of a function are time-consuming.

AHH I see what you mean! Sorry about that. I have edited my answer

@Friede:  Read the docs for Rprof().  You can get it to profile by source line by using line.profiling = TRUE (as long as you kept line info in the functions).

@user2554330, please have a look at the edits made and the timestamps of the comments. Thank you.

@JoshAllen The profvis method seems to be what I am looking for. However, why does it need to be sourced in as a script vs loaded into the environment? If I run it just with my original code, it errors could not find function "sys.sleep"

@acircleda just a typo it is Sys.sleep . Why source vs profvis({function_to_test}) from what I gather from the faq page Sys.sleep won't register so you have to trick it a little bit. Why source tricks it I honestly have no idea
